# Connected to ethernet but no internet or outgoing connections

Tags: internet, ethernet, connection, wired

I am connected to Ethernet "wired connection 1"; I can see that in the network manager (the up and down arrows).

But when I open up Firefox or anything else that requires internet connection I get told the same thing; no internet connection.

```
$ ifconfig
 enp3s0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:de:80:c7:fd:2b  
       inet6 addr: fe80::f527:1269:a6f5:57e5/64 Scope:Link
       inet6 addr: 2001:878:3ac:163:8a7:7349:6e60:d84/64 Scope:Global
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
       RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
       RX bytes:848 (848.0 B)  TX bytes:288 (288.0 B)

 lo Link encap:Local Loopback  
       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
       RX packets:2292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:2292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
       RX bytes:171576 (171.5 KB)  TX bytes:171576 (171.5 KB)
```

I should note that no other devices have trouble connecting to the router nor does Windows 7 when I dual boot to that.

When I do `ping google.com` I get:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

when I do `cat /etc/network/interfaces` I get:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo iface lo inet loopback auto eth iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Ubuntu version 16.04.

If you need more information, please do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If enp3s0 is your default interface for Ethernet connection, then we can see that there is no IP assigned to it.

Try the following command:

> ping www.google.com

If the pong is successful then there is internet  connection. If you find the output as

> cannot resolve host

Then you need to check your network configuration page to find whether DHCP and DNS is enabled or not.
Can you please provide the output of

> /etc/network/interfaces

file. For Ubuntu 16.04 location may vary.

Comment: the BOLD part of interfaces(5) is because it has a # in front of it.

Comment: Here it is showing the interface as eth0, but your showing the output of eth0. Are you having eth0 interface?

Comment: Try the command ifconfig. From the ping result we can see that you are not having dns-nameserver set. Hence we canmot resolve the host.